# Oracle Data Provider for .NET does not support Time

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle

i'm trying to use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client with ASP.NET identity and on method:

```
await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

getting error:

Oracle Data Provider for .NET does not support Time

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Oracle Data Provider for .NET does not support Time

Maybe someone has solved this issue? SigninManager is default ASP.NET Identity manager.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle database does not have a TIME data type.  The DATE and the various flavors of TIMESTAMP include both date and time.

Comment: Can you provide example? Because Identity implementation is from Microsoft, so how can i find which property is TIME data type?

Comment: How can I provide an example of that which does not exist? I say again, oracle _does not have a data type for TIME alone_.  Time is included in DATE and TIMESTAMP.  Documentation for those are found at https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#sthref117.  I've also written about it at https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/category/dealing-with-dates/

Comment: maybe someone has implemented ASP.NET Identity with Oracle DB? Because i can't find which property is TIME data type. I ignored this propertie: DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc , but still getting the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Problem was found: when you getting this error, the problem with .NET data type is with TimeSpan datatype, not Datetime, i changed TimeSpan to Datetime, and this error was gone.